# can't get liquibase executeCommand changeset to do anything

Tags: liquibase

From the [liquibase docs](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/execute_command.html), it looks like an `executeCommand` changeset should just shell out and execute the given command (e.g., `mysqldump`).  But if I specify some changeset like

```
<changeSet author="me" id="test">
    <executeCommand executable="date" />
</changeSet>
```

then all I get is this error message

```
2016-07-20 10:02:43,675 ERROR [main] liquibase
```

even though the changeset gets marked as `EXECUTED` in the db.

Even if I specify some different executable like a tiny test shell script, it doesn't look like it actually gets executed.

Is there anything else that I need to specify in the changeset, or do I have some incorrect expectation about how an `executeCommand` changeset should work?

Comment: If this is intended to be run on Windows, you would need to run "cmd /c date" because date is not an executable, but a built-in command in the cmd shell. Depending on your needs, you may also need to mark the changeset with the attribute 'runAlways=true', otherwise it will only run once.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I was running this on OS X.  I'm able to repeat the attempted execution of the changeset by removing the appropriate row from the DATABASECHANGELOG table.